# How to register a plugin to run on Update and on Create of an entity?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, registration, step

How can I run my plugin both on **Create** and **Update** of an entity ? 
Should I create two steps one with message Update and one with "Create" ?

I'm not quite sure of my understanding of "Steps", are they steps that are performed consecutively or do they represent an "If" like: run this plugin "If" an entity is created and run this plugin "If" an entity is updated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add two different steps but can still point these to the same plugin.  Then in the plugin you can check the context.MessageName to see what message has been passed into the plugin and then do different actions depending on the result.

Example for condition check:

```
 if (context.MessageName == “Create”)
    {
    }
 if (context.MessageName == “Update”) 
    {
    }
```

Comment: @user3340627 Maks is right, you should register two steps
1. Create
2. Update

If you have different business logic on create then check in plugin for context.MessageName

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I just did that but there seems to be something else wrong. When my plugin fires on an Update of phonecall for example, I get null recipients and null senders in the target entity. Do you have an idea why that might happen ?

Comment: I found that the problem is because Update only sends the changed fields in the target entity. The solution is to use a pre-image. An explanation is here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629825/why-is-crm-2011-entity-relationship-null-in-this-plugin-code